# Why doenst my Update query have an effect on my table content?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that depicts future flight arrival times. After each flight arrival time has past (or expired) I would like the query to update the arrival time by inserting the next arrival time, which is usually a week from the current day/time.

Although my query doesn't yield any error messages, it doesn't have an effect on expired arrival times as it should.

Find below the query:

// The update should happen between 31 minutes to and hour after the flight has arrived.

```sql
UPDATE flightSched
SET `arrivalTime`= ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
WHERE arrivalTime BETWEEN SUBTIME(NOW(), '00:31:00')
                 AND SUBTIME(NOW(),'01:00:00')
                 ORDER BY arrivalTime ASC
```

Find below a simlpe version of my table:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
| FlightNo    | arrivalTime         | 
+-------------+---------------------+
| ET821       | 2013-11-24 08:05:24 |
| MS838       | 2013-11-24 10:05:24 |
| H7361       | 2013-11-24 13:15:06 |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

If the current time is 09:45, then flight number ET821 arrival time should be updated to 2013-12-01 08:05:24, Please help me understand why this update doesn't happen?

Comment: What value do you see when you enter SELECT SUBTIME( NOW( ) , '00:31:00' ) ? Also ORDER BY is only used for SELECT queries when results are returned. No results are returned for an UPDATE query so there is nothing to order.

Comment: If the current time is `09:45` then according to your requirements arrival time of flight `MS838` should be changed, not `ET821`. Right?

Comment: @peterm Correct MS838 should change

Comment: @WebChemist good point, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @WebChemist Actually MySQL **supports** `ORDER BY` clause in `UPDATE` statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html. *If an UPDATE statement includes an ORDER BY clause, the rows are updated in the order specified by the clause. This can be useful in certain situations that might otherwise result in an error.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update doesn't produce any results because your date range in `WHERE` clause is incorrect. The upper value in `BETWEEN` operator is less than the lower value.

According to your requirements instead of

```
BETWEEN SUBTIME(NOW(), '00:31:00') AND SUBTIME(NOW(),'01:00:00')
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

it should be at least

```
BETWEEN SUBTIME(NOW(), '00:31:00') AND ADDTIME(NOW(),'01:00:00')
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

Try it the other way

```sql
UPDATE flightSched
   SET arrivalTime = arrivalTime + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
 WHERE arrivalTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 31 MINUTE
   AND arrivalTime <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

**Note:** make sure that you have an index on `arrivalTime` column.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/602aa/1)** demo